# How to return data type with input?

Tags: python, input, floating-point, integer

I'm brand new to python and am using the "Job Ready for Python" as a first text and ran across this chapter 4 problem that I can't get my head around:

*Create a program that prompts the user to a number and then displays the type of number entered(e.g., complex, integer, or a float).*

I'm having a hard time understanding how to classify inputs as anything other than strings -- additionally in the book I have covered basics, variables, booleans, and operators: and (per the book) should have all the tools to do this

Any help would be appreciated

I tried something like

```python
num = input("Type any number: ")
print(num, ":", type(num))
```

but that kept returning string....

and then I thought maybe I have to classify values using operators such as

```python
num = input(....)
if num % 2 == x
```

IDK from hear

Comment: this is a duplicate question and will likely get flagged -- I would read through the [python docs on data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). built-in functions like `str()` and `int()` allow you to convert between types when dealing with numeric values

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Resource. The issue I’m running into is that the problem is asking me to have a user input some number and then have the program return what type of number that is but I can’t foresee what number or non number they will submit so I can’t tell a specific variable to be integer or floor etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, whenever you take input from user. It is always a string.

```python
age = input("Enter your age :")
print(type(age))
```

This will print `str`.

To convert this, you can do this,

```python
age = int(input("Enter your age :"))
print(type(age))
```

This will print `int`.

Comment: Thank you I did understand this concept. The issue was that the exercise wants me to have the program determine what type of number were dealing with integer float or complex but I can’t preset the variable to be one or the other I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This basic code seems to work for me; not sure why the previous answerer claims it does not:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat getType.py
age = input("Enter your age :")
print(type(age))
Mac_3.2.57$python getType.py
Enter your age :22
<type 'int'>
Mac_3.2.57$python getType.py
Enter your age :22.0
<type 'float'>
Mac_3.2.57$python getType.py
Enter your age :22 + 23j
<type 'complex'>
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: presumably your `input` is doing something extra!  the [CPython standard builtin](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7bae15cf37239d4d345e09cc318bd82d03ec30cd/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2072) always returns a `str`.  at a guess you're `eval`ing the `str`, maybe via a modification to your `site.py`

Comment: I do like this solve the method the only issue is at this point in the book I have yet to learn about the method getType.py. But I appreciate your input

Comment: @John Avant  "getType.py" is just the name of the file that I picked, I could have called it "answerToStackoverflowQuestion74595996v0.py" or something else.

Comment: @Sam Mason  raw_input() takes a str, maybe that is what you are thinking of?  I don't get the point of your source code link.

Comment: ah, you're using Python 2!  The link I posted is the C code behind `input` for Python 3.10.  This would be the equivalent of `raw_input` in Python 2.  Might be pointing out that you're using something this old, it's been ["end-of-life" since 2020](https://endoflife.date/python).

Comment: So, in 3.10, I guess, you need to use try blocks to solve this?  I'm sticking with 2!

Comment: `help(input)` suggests Python 2.7's `input()` is equivalent to `eval(input())` in 3.  if I type `na` in I get `NameError: name 'na' is not defined` back from these (i.e. `input()` in 2.7 and `eval(input())` in 3.10).  not sure how sticking with 2 helps, here or elsewhere.  most of the libraries I care about only support Python 3 now